# How to change (D:) into (E:)

Tags: bios

I have tried to change the letter of my new drive. I currently have the (C:) and the new one I am trying to change is to (E:) from D

I have tried to change it under Server Management & Disk Management.

The problem that I am having is that the letter E is not an option from both drop down selections.

I have even tried to change my (C:) into the E but again, it's not even a choice.

I was told I could change it in BIOS. Does anyone know how to? If it's possible

Comment: Is `E` already in use?

Comment: Could you be so kind to add a screenshot of disk management to your question?

Comment: If the option to change to E is not available then *something* is already using it. You should find out what that is and change that first.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not able to take my phone in the area.   I do not believe E is in use because I am not able to see it anywhere but that is probably the issue.

Comment: Something is mounted to E somewhere in the system. If you are not an administrator, its possible this is hidden from you. Things that can claim the driveletter: another disk or drive (including DVD), a network share, USB thumb drive or even a folder to drive substitution (subst). If your computer has multiple users, another user may have created the network mapping. In rare cases, if you remove a drive letter, but something keeps that device occupied, explorer will stop showing the drive, but it remains active until that task ends or the system is rebooted.

Comment: What does not being able to take your phone into the area have to do with this? Is this a specialized computer in a secured environment? Have you spoken with the designated computer support staff? BIOS doesn't control drive letters. If E isn't available this means it's being used somewhere else. Usually this means you find what IS E drive, changed that to something else, then change your D to E.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure *Markus Meyer* and *Mokubai* are right: Something is using the drive letter. (For example an empty DVD/CD-drive.)

1. **In case it's really the DVD/CD-drive:**
   *Insert a media > Check the drive letter > Change the drive letter in the tool of your choice to free E: > Change the drive letter of your current D: to E: > DONE.*
2. **If not such easy:**
   Open a command shell with administrative privileges and issue these commands:

```
diskpart.exe         # Start the disk management tool "DiskPart".
list volume          # Show the known volumes and their assigned drive letters
                     #   I assume "Volume 0" has "E:" assigned.
select volume 0      # Select the volume that as "E:" assigned.
                     #   Replace "0" respectively.
assign letter=G      # Change the drive letter of the selected volume to
                     #   an unused one. I supposed G: as free.
list volume          # Check the success. Now you should see G: instead of E:.
select volume 2      # Change to the volume that shall get the letter E:
                     #   Here I assume it is No. 2. (Your's has D: you wrote)
assign letter=E      # Change the drive letter (currently D:) 
list volume          # Check the success. Now you should see E: instead of D:.
exit                 # Leave "DiskPart"
exit                 # Close the command shell.
```

Now you're done.

---

> I was told I could change it in BIOS. Does anyone know how to? If it's possible

Changing the drive letter by the BIOS order is a matter of the auto-assignement functionality (first recognized volume gets the lowest drive letter). You have to change the order the drives are recognized.

But the volume of question must not yet be known to the installed Windows
AND the drive letter in question must not be reserved already
AND you do not wish to have a gap in the letter assignements.

=> Tuning the BIOS for this is not really an option, especially as you want to omit D:.

Answer (score -1):

In many cases you need to reboot to fully engage the new drive letter.  Then the old vacated drive letter should be available.